# Insertar en un input la fecha a día de hoy

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Quiero establecer la fecha del día de hoy en este *input*:

```html
<label class="control-label">Hasta</label> 
<input type="date" id = "hasta" class="date-range-filter" placeholder="From: yyyy-mm-dd">
```

Ejecuto esto:

```html
n =  new Date();
//Año
  year = n.getFullYear();
//Mes
  month = n.getMonth() + 1;
//Día
  day = n.getDate();
  dia2= (zfill(day,2))
  document.getElementById("hasta").value = year + "-" + month + "-" + dia2;
```

Funciona cuando el tipo del input es text, pero quiero que siga manteniendo el tipo: date.
Gracias. (zfill es para ponerle dos dígitos a los días)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo yo mismo por si alguien lo necesita:

```html
 n =  new Date();
//Año
   year = n.getFullYear();
//Mes
  month = n.getMonth() + 1;
//Día
  day = n.getDate();
  dia2= (zfill(day,2))

  var newFecha = `${year}-${month}-${dia2}`
   $("#hasta").val(newFecha);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona tu código. Lee [answer]. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.